# Setting paragraphs inside \setlayer

Tags: context, context-mkiv, layers

I am trying to use layers to define a letterhead, but I am finding that text set using a `\setlayers` command often is set as a single paragraph, even when explicit paragraph layout commands are used, such as `\startlines`.  The following MWE also shows that I have managed to get line breaking respected when I use a start-stop environment defined using `\defineparagraphs`:

```
 \definelayer[letterheadtop][x=0mm,y=0mm,height=0.3\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]
 \definelayer[letterheadbottom][x=0mm,y=0.8\paperheight,height=0.2\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]
 \noheaderandfooterlines 

 \starttext

 \setlayer[letterheadtop][hoffset=0mm,voffset=0mm]{% 
   \framed[width=2in]{Logo}
 }

 \setlayer[letterheadtop][hoffset=0.6\paperwidth,voffset=0mm]{% 
   \startlines %This all collapses onto one line
     Line 1
     Line 2
     Line 3
   \stoplines
 }

 \setlayer[letterheadbottom][hoffset=0mm,voffset=0mm]{% 
   \defineparagraphs[lhpar][n=2,before={\blank},after={\blank}]   
   \setupparagraphs [lhpar][1][width=.5\paperwidth] 

   \startlhpar % left column
     Left
   \lhpar % switch to right column
   \startlines %These line breaks are respected
     Line 1
     Line 2
     Line 3
   \stoplines
   \stoplhpar % end paragraph body 
 }

 \setupbackgrounds[page][background={letterheadtop,letterheadbottom}] 

    Some text

 \stoptext
```

What is going on here? How can I get my line breaks respected within the `\setlayer` command?

Comment: Either use `\setlayer[...]{\framed[...]{...}}` or the equivalent `\setlayerframed[....][...]{...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\setlayer` typesets its content in a `\hbox`. You can use `\setlayerframed` to typeset the content in a `\vbox`. For example:

```
 \setlayerframed[letterheadtop]
                [hoffset=0.6\paperwidth,voffset=0mm]
                [align=normal,frame=off,strut=no]
                {\startlines[before=,after=]
                  Line 1
                  Line 2
                  Line 3
                \stoplines}
```

where the first optional arguments correspond to the arguments for `\setlayer` and the second optional arguments correspond to the arguments for `\framed`.

`\defineparagraphs` works because it explicitly typesets the content in a `\vbox`.

Comment: When you set only one optional argument the values are passed to `\setlayer` and `\framed` and only when you use both (which can be empty) you can set separate values for them.

Comment: @Metafox hello. How's everything?. I'll delete this comment eventually. But just out of curiosity, why do you normally address only Aditya. I mean, Is it possible that you could also, (if it's not an inconvenience for you of course) address the op too? Normally you address only the former. If you could, out of courtesy, take care of that problem, it would be great. Your insights and knowledge are appreciated nonetheless.